# What would cause a babel transformation Syntax Error w an Unexpected Character

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm working to add twemoji to my application, whether I add twemoji using their NPM package or directly import the JS file (https://github.com/twitter/twemoji/blob/gh-pages/twemoji.npm.js) I get an error.

This is the error that occurs when I try to load my app (yarn run watch), and I can't even get the error to go away after a `yarn cache clean` and reinstall. I have to delete my directory and redownload from github and start fresh.

```
/home/circleci/repo/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:558
      throw err;
      ^

SyntaxError: /home/circleci/repo/packages/my-ui/assets/imgs/services/google.png: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
> 1 | �PNG
    | ^
  2 | 
  3 | 
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I've been racking my brain trying to figure out why this is happening and why one my app does break I can't get the app back into a working state.

I've identified that the issue is with the twemoji library, I just don't know why.

After looking at the twemoji library and my error does anyone have any ideas what the issue could be?

**UPDATE**
There is nothing wrong with the image. The error was not occurring before, and even if I delete the image, the app errors on the next image. And I've confirmed the images are valid PNGs.

Comment: Could you include your `babel-loader` Webpack configuration?

Comment: It's possible there's a non-visible (to you) Unicode character in your code. That can happen when cutting/pasting from the web sometimes. Try deleting the code in the area of the error and re-typing it (not re-copying; type it yourself).

Comment: is there a way to search for a non-visible using the terminal? I also just ATOM for my IDE... Or a way to search on github for this?

Comment: Please show the code you're using and the relevant webpack config. Looks like it's just inserting the PNG data as-is into your JS file.

Comment: "I've confirmed the images are valid PNGs". You shouldn't be loading images into Babel in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a file loader in your app [file-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-loader)
than include following code in your Webpack config file

```
{
  test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/,
  use: [{loader:'file-loader'}],
},
```